# How to change the engline type from InnoDb to MyISAM of an existing db?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, myisam, storage-engine

I have a MariaDb database which consists of 2 tables and which is around 10Gb of the size. One is dependendant on the other via a foreign key.

How can I change the engine type of that particular db from InnoDb to MyISAM?

Comment: You should at least consider `Aria` as an alternative that has crash safety. What are you hoping to achieve with these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply answer your question, I would turn off foreign key checks and unique checks, then convert it

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You should remove the foreign key afterwards.

Why you do want to change it to MyISAM is another story.